# Is it possible for Oracle to insert two rows with the same created date?

Tags: date, triggers, insert, oracle11g

I'm running an Oracle 11g RAC.

I have a `FOR EACH ROW BEFORE INSERT` trigger on my table that populates the `CREATED_DATE (DATE)` using `sysdate`.

What granularity does the `DATE` datatype have? Is it possible in a RAC for two rows to have the exact same `INSERT` date/time when populated via a trigger like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easily posssible even without RAC.

```
17:25:47 (455)SYSTEM@dwal> create table t (k int primary key, d date);

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.35
17:32:00 (455)SYSTEM@dwal> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\dwal\BUF_SYSTEM_455.sql

  1  create trigger t_bi before insert on t for each row
  2  begin
  3  :new.d := sysdate;
  4* end;
17:32:04 (455)SYSTEM@dwal> /

Trigger created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10
17:32:04 (455)SYSTEM@dwal> insert into t(k) select rownum from dual connect by rownum <= 1e3;

1000 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
17:32:30 (455)SYSTEM@dwal> select d, count(*) from t group by d;

D                     COUNT(*)
------------------- ----------
18.09.2013 17:32:37       1000

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

DATE type has granularity of seconds, if you want something more granular you might want to use TIMESTAMP:

```
17:34:51 (455)SYSTEM@dwal> alter table t add (ts timestamp);

Table altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.17
17:36:01 (455)SYSTEM@dwal> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\dwal\BUF_SYSTEM_455.sql

  1  create or replace trigger t_bi before insert on t for each row
  2  begin
  3  :new.d := sysdate;
  4  :new.ts := systimestamp;
  5* end;
17:36:05 (455)SYSTEM@dwal> /

Trigger created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.13
17:36:05 (455)SYSTEM@dwal> insert into t(k) select rownum from dual connect by rownum <= 1e3;

1000 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.12
17:36:47 (455)SYSTEM@dwal> select d, min(ts) mn, max(ts) mx, count(*) from t group by d;

D                   MN                             MX                               COUNT(*)
------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
18.09.2013 17:36:19 18-SEP-13 05.36.19.481071 PM   18-SEP-13 05.36.19.593846 PM         1000

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref152):

> *For each DATE value, Oracle stores the following information: year, month, day, hour, minute, and second*

So if two inserts happen in the same second, then yes the columns can have the same value.

If you need more fine grained time information you should use a `TIMESTAMP` column which can also store fractional seconds up to 9 digits. But on a high traffic system I would think that it can still happen that two inserts happen at the same millisecond

Comment: up to 9 digits, actually. 6 goes by default if you don't specify precision.

Answer (score 1):

When you reference sysdate in a SQL statement, only a single value of sysdate is used.

So if you performed an insert of 1,000,000 records that included assigning sysdate to a CREATED_AT column, and the insert took fifteen minutes, then all 1,000,000 records would have the same CREATED_AT value.

However, when the value of CREATED_AT is populated by a trigger I believe that its value will be re-evaluated for every trigger execution. There's a discussion of it at [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1633985837904). One of the conclusions of that is that when you need to use SYSDATE in a function called from SQL it might be necessary to pass in the value of SYSDATE from the SQL statement if timings are critical, as a long-running statement or procedure could be referencing multiple values of SYSDATE.

I believe that the same would apply to TIMESTAMP values.

So, you cannot rely on the created_at column to provide uniqueness. That is something that should be achieved through a sequence generated value.